# Factor/Quotient Group $M/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-groups

I've posted another question here a few days ago asking what a factor/quotient group is because I couldn't wrap my mind around it. Although I have an idea what it means, I still don't fully understand it and why we use it. So can you please tell me what the following factor group means explicitly:

$M=\left\{ m\times13^{-n}\mid m\in\mathbb{Z}\wedge n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} $
with $\mathbb{Z}\leq M\leq\mathbb{Q}$

So how does $M/\mathbb{Z}$ look, what does factoring to $\mathbb{Z}$ mean?

I need to prove that a subgroup $H\leq M/\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic.

(don't start with $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ or examples like that, i already got that)

Comment: According to your profile, this is the only question you've asked.

Comment: Please, check my edit.

Comment: The easiest way for me, personally, to grasp this group is to view it as a subgroup of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$. Now, $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is the group of rationals "mod $1$" meaning that if we write our fractions as mixed fractions "$a\frac bc$", then we can ignore the $a$. E.g. $1\frac12=2\frac12=25\frac12=\dots=\frac12$. (I *finally* found a use for mixed fractions!)

Comment: Do you need to prove that a cyclic subgroup $H$ *exists*? Do you need to prove that *any* subgroup $H$ is cyclic? Or do you need to prove from *some specific* subgroup $H$ (which one?) that it is cyclic? Be more specific.

Comment: It has to be any subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a heuristic, the factor group $G/H$ is what you get when you want to consider elements of $G$, but don't really care about difference by elements of $H$.

As an example, in calculus, when studying the behavior of a function at the origin, it's often useful to consider it up to first order, i.e. write $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + x^2( \ldots)$.  So here $G$ could be power series in $x$ under addition, and $H$ could be power series with $a_0 = a_1 = 0$; in the quotient $G/H$ we just take functions up to first order, i.e. from $f$ we remember only $a_0 + a_1x$.

As another example, in the Dihedral group $D_{2n}$, you could be only interested in whether your symmetry preserves or reverses orientation. In this case, since rotations preserve orientation, you would want $D_{2n}/\mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

As to your examples, $M$ is plainly just rational numbers with only powers of 13 in the denominator. As Karl Kronenfeld helpfully says in the comments, when you don't care about difference by $\mathbb{Z}$, all you are left with is the fractional parts (mod 1).

Let's see any (proper) subgroup $H$ is cyclic. Suppose the fractional parts of elements of $H$ get arbitrarily close to 0, it follows that the powers of 13 in the denominators of $H$ grow arbitrarily big, i.e. we have $\frac{a}{13^k} \in H$ with $(a, 13) = 1$, and $k$ arbitrarily large.  Since $(a,13^k) = 1$, we can write $an + 13^km = 1$, with $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, so we also have $\frac{na}{13^k} + \frac{m13^k}{13^k} = \frac{1}{13^k}$ in $H$, i.e. $H =G$.

So any proper subgroup $H$ has bounded denominators, say all bounded by $13^k$. It follows that $H$ is a subgroup of the one generated by $\frac{1}{13^k}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/13^k \mathbb{Z}$. Since a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, we're done :).

Comment: Thanks! It was so simple, but it just had to be explained in a simple manner and not like textbooks explain it. I still have a question. What is a in this case? Is it an integer? And also, if you could help me, i need to prove that G is not finitely generated and that G/H ~ G.

Comment: Also, only now I have thought of this. A cyclic group is a group generated by only one element. But 1/13^k is not just one element. You can give k values in the set of natural numbers. Can help me on that? I'm sure I am not understanding something properly.

Comment: Hi Chanbalna - sorry for the delayed response. $a$ was indeed an integer; in the last paragraph $k$ is now some fixed number, such that noone in $H$ lies between $0$ and $\frac{1}{13^k}$. For finite generation, think about how close to 0 you can get with sums of only finitely many guys, for $G/H \sim G$, if $H$ is generated by $1/13^k$, instead of folding over 1 now you fold over $1/13^k$, but otherwise it looks the same.